# Excel: How to return a column using Xlookup dynamically

Tags: excel, xlookup

Im trying to specify which column to return when using Xlookup but not sure how to go about this. Sample data below:

[image]

My formula `=XLOOKUP(1,(C3:C6="Bob")*(D3:D6="LA"),G3:G6)` gets the value of column G where name is Bob and city is LA returning 78.8 in this case. However I want to be able to dynamically specify which column is to be returned out of E,F & G similar to how Vlookup can specify a column number to return, because I wont know ahead of time which column to return. How can I specify the column number to return instead of hardcoding a range

Comment: How formula will determine which column to return? What is logic to specify column?

Comment: If you want just specify column number instead of range then could try `=INDEX(E3:G6,MATCH("Bob" & "LA",C3:C6&D3:D6,0),3)`.

Comment: "_I want to be able to dynamically specify which column is to be returned..._"  What does that mean?  Describe how "dynamically specify" works.

Comment: @Harun24HR The users of the spreadsheet will specify which column to return. From their data entry I'm able to tell which column they need eg column 5. But I dont know how to use this column number in the xlookup.

Comment: @Harun24HR That works perfectly! Seems xlookup was not suited for what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @West Welcome! See my answer and please accept (tick mark it) if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many ways to do that. Try below one-

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(C3:C6="Bob")*(D3:D6="LA"),INDEX(E3:G6,,3))
```

[image]

Another way is using `Index()/Match()` combination.

```
=INDEX(E3:G6,MATCH("Bob" & "LA",C3:C6&D3:D6,0),3)
```